# Is there a quick way to convert ArrayList<List<Object>> into Google's List<RowData>

Tags: java, android, google-sheets-api

Hello: Need some help on how to convert an `ArrayList<List<Object>>` into `List<RowData>`

I am using Google Spreadsheet API V4 on Java

**Here is my Array List:**

```
ArrayList<List<Object>> rowsData = oCoreGoogle.ReadExcel(sheetname);
```

**And, here is the RowData that i want to write to the spreadsheet.**
I am lost into finding if there is a native way to quickly convert `ArrayList<List<Object>>` into `List<RowData>`.

```
List<RowData> rowData = new ArrayList<RowData>();

requests.add(new Request()
                .setAppendCells(new AppendCellsRequest()
                        .setSheetId(1929014238)
                        .setRows(rowData)
                        .setFields("userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat.numberFormat")
                        )
```

Comment: What is `RowData`? Is this your own custom class? If so, add a method that returns a `List<Object>`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, Thanks for your time. [RowData](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/RowData.html) is a google spreadsheet api class